# Force download headers dont work as expected

Tags: php, download, http-headers, file-get-contents

I was expecting that for each link found on the webpage the script could download a html file on my pc, asking me where to put the file(in which folder)... but instead the code download all the files on a folder on the server (the same where the php file is). I even try to erase the force download but nothing change.

What I do wrong? Thanks in advance.

this is my code:

```
$srcUrl= 'http://www.example.com/index.php';
$base= 'http://www.example.com/';

$html = file_get_contents($srcUrl);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

// grab all the on the page
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

//finding the a tag
$hrefs = $xpath->evaluate("/html/body//a");

header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header('Content-type: text/html');


//Loop to display all the links and download
for ($i = 0; $i < $hrefs->length; $i++) {
    $href = $hrefs->item($i);
    $url = $href->getAttribute('href');

    //if real link
    if($url!='#') {

        //check if url is ok
        $www= filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, FILTER_FLAG_PATH_REQUIRED);

if ($www == false )
{
       //change the bad ones in absolute url;
        $url2 = make_absolute($url, $base);


        //Code to get the file...
        $data = file_get_contents($url2);

        //save as?
        $filename = $url;

        file_put_contents($filename, $data);

        //a time to rest
        sleep(5);
    }

    }
}

?>
```

Comment: you cannot download multiple files in a single http request, especially sicne you're only outputting your filename header ONCE. your code could easily output the contents of multiple files, but they'd all be saved into the SAME single file on the client. and in any case, nowhere do you have `echo $data` to actually send the file contents to the user.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Do you have any advice about how I could solve the problem?

Comment: make an archive on the server that contains all of the files you want, e.g. a zip file, and send that out instead.